# loading xml from properties file

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties

is it possible to load data from a properties file to xml file using spring? if yes can anyone give an example of that?

here is the xml:

```
<cluster balancer="load" 
       dialect="net.sf.hajdbc.dialect.MySQLDialect" 
       default-sync="full" 
       transaction-mode="parallel" 
       auto-activate-schedule="0 * * ? * *" 
       failure-detect-schedule="0 * * ? * *"
       meta-data-cache="none">
<database id="database1">
  <driver>***</driver>
  <url>***</url>
  <user>***</user>
  <password>***</password>
</database>
```

here is the datasource

```
database.driver=***

database1.url=***
database1.username=***
database1.password=***
```

Comment: hi guys, i added an example for you to understand.

Comment: this depends on the library that reads the XML file - unless you don't want to replace (i.e. edit) the placeholders inside the file and read it afterwards

Comment: Still have no idea what you're asking. You're giving some sample 'xml' but you want to load data from a properties file? What is the relevance of the data source and what is it? Please rephrase your question so someone who doesn't know about your problem can actually understand it.

Comment: i dont know where the complexity is, if you know the answer it should be simple, there is an xml, there is a properties file, need to get the data from properties to xml, but wont use any java code, would not mind using a framework or a library

Comment: if anyone knows how to put it in a spring config file please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Spring for that. What you have to do is extract the properties using getProperty(). An example follows:

```
    File propertiesFile = ...
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(propertiesFile);
    properties.load(fis);

    String databaseDriver = properties.getProperty("database.driver");
    String database1Url = properties.getProperty("database1.url");
    String database1Username = properties.getProperty("database1.username");
```

(I left out exceptions for the sake of simplicity)

and use the Java API for XML to create your XML file. An example how to begin creating XML follows:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = document.createElement("database");
document.appendChild(rootElement);

...
```

google "java create xml" or similar to find out how to create the xml according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Spring properties file, it is already XML. You can read this with the standard Java XML parsing libraries if you are so inclined. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/ has several turorials on various methods to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to read a Spring file without Spring, but it is possible.

Comment: actually i dont want to use any parsing using java, i just wanted to know if there is any way like the way spring does, if you can derive data from properties file to xml.

Comment: well Spring uses Java to parse the XML :-)

Comment: yeah but i dont need to write the java codes for spring, its there already. anyhow, waiting for someone who knows it.

Comment: Um, if you don't want to use Spring's implementation, you have to write your own. **You don't have a choice.** There are no libraries to do this, because Spring already did it.

Comment: i never said i dont want to use spring, i was just saying i dont want to write any java code. let me know if you can do that with spring, and how using my sample. thanks.

Comment: Actually, you DID say that you wanted to do this without using Spring.  Read your question again.

Comment: ok i have changed it to using spring now, i hope someone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to load data from a properties file to xml file without using spring?

Yes, but only if you write a whole bunch of Java code to:

1. read the XML and extract the details that you need.
2. load the properties
3. merge the details from the properties into the details.

I'm not aware of any generic solution to this problem apart from Spring.

---

Actually, I'm not sure that you can do *exactly* this using Spring either.

Spring DI wiring has  mechanisms for substituting complete bean property values (`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`) or placeholders embedded in property values (`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`).  However, POC and PPC operate on the values of bean properties declared in Spring bean definitions.  What you have in your example looks like plain XML ... not Spring bean declarations.

Comment: hi stephen, could you let me know if you can put that xml in spring config and make it work?

Comment: see that was my original problem, let me break it down for you. the xml is needed for ha-jdbc and ha-jdbc pulls the info from the xml, now i need to put the information on a properties file, which will be pulled into the xml and then in the app. makes sense?